# Condense a logistic function around its midpoint

Tags: self-learning, linear-algebra

I have a function

$$
f(x) = {1 \over 1 + e^{-k(x-0.5)}}
$$

that plots a logistic curve that is symmetric around the point $0.5 / 0.5$.

$k$ defines the steepness of the curve.

I would now like to add another parameter (let's call it $c$) that stretches/condenses the curve on the y-axis while it stays symmetric around its midpoint $0.5 / 0.5$.

**How/where would I add $c$ to this function?**

Comment: That's such an interesting question! But it's a math question, not a math education question. Please post it on math.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: Is there ANY stackexchange forum where normal math users can post their math questions? Everyone feels too posh to accept this question, but at least I got the answer here. Thank you @justin-skycak <3

Comment: Rather than `0.5 / 0.5`, that should be typeset as $0.5/0.5.$ Similarly $k$ and $c.$ I.e, with dollar signs. $\qquad$

Comment: If this helps people to understand the question, so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift it down so it's symmetric to $y=0,$ then stretch it, then shift it back up so that it's symmetric to $y=0.5$ again.

$$f(x) = c \left( \dfrac{1}{1 + e^{-k(x-0.5)}} - 0.5 \right) + 0.5$$

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) Now I remember what I once learned at school but forgot long ago :-D

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to answer off-topic questions. I think you should ask the OP to post it at an appropriate site, then you answer it there.

Comment: Toooo late  I don't think that all the gatekeeping on SE sites does well to the communities. You could at least tell me which of the sites would have been "right". Because I tried all that are related to math and here I got the answer. So it appears to be the right one.

Comment: @Fred I don't think that this question, as currently phrased, is a very good question for *any* SE site.  It isn't about Math Education, so it doesn't belog here; and it is lacking context, so it wouldn't be appropriate on Math.  I can't think of any other site on the SE network where it would fit.  It might be more appropriate for another site (like reddit) or for the SE chat system.

Comment: How does the context help to understand the question? It's about stretching a function. It could be just for intellectual purposes without any more thoughts behind it. So how would you phrase it?